# How to list files in a backslashed directory name?

Tags: linux, shell

I have seen a strange directory on my linux server.. Here it is:

**drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         4096 Jan 12  2005 \t\t\t\t/**

How can i escape \t under shell?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`"\t\t\t\t"` or `\\t\\t\\t\\t`

Answer (score 2):

"\t" may be a tab character.  That is, the directory's name may be `<tab><tab><tab><tab>`.  You can try combinations of literal \ (which needs to be escaped, so you type `\\`) and `t` and tab or use globbing.  I'd recommend globbing, so (assuming there are no other oddly named directories in this directory)

```
mv \<tab>* mystery-dir
mv \\* mystery-dir
mv \\t* mystery-dir
```

one of these should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing that with the `-b` option of `ls`, then those are tab characters. Here is one way rename it:

```
mv $'\t\t\t\t' new_name
```

In this case, you type the individual backslash and "t" characters and the `$'...'` converts it to tabs for you. It makes it easier to read the command than trying to insert the right number of tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly.